# How can one change the default font size and the text color in the quote environment?

Tags: quotation

How can one change the font size and color of the text in the "quote" environment?

Answer (score 3):

With an up-to-date LaTeX system (released on 2020-10-01 or later), it's very easy:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\AddToHook{env/quote/begin}{\small\color{blue!70}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[3][1-4]
\begin{quote}
\lipsum[4][1-4]
\end{quote}
\lipsum[4][1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you look in `article.cls` (similar if you are using a different class) `quote` is defined by

```
\newenvironment{quote}
               {\list{}{\rightmargin\leftmargin}%
                \item\relax}
               {\endlist}
```

so in your document you can use

```
\renewenvironment{quote}
               {\list{}{\rightmargin\leftmargin}%
                \item\relax\large\color{red}}
               {\endlist}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want the user interface to be but the following gives you a couple of options.

```
% quoteprob.tex  SE 605141
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{comment}

\newenvironment{myquote}%  %%% using the \Large font
  {\begin{list}{}%
    {\setlength\rightmargin{\leftmargin}}%
  %% set the font size (and color?)
  \Large
  \item[]\makebox[0pt]{}%[r]{``}
     \ignorespaces}%
 {\unskip\makebox[0pt]{}%[l]{''}
  \end{list}}

\begin{document}

Some random words just to see the width of the textblock.
Plus some more random words just to see the width of the textblock.


\begin{quote}
  This is in a regular \verb!quote! environment. Have a look at the font size
  compared with the normal font size.
\end{quote}

Some random words just to see the width of the textblock.
Plus some more random words just to see the width of the textblock.

\begin{quote}
  \footnotesize
  This is in a regular \verb!quote! environment with \verb!\footnotesize!. Have a look at the font size
  compared with the normal font size.
\end{quote}


Some random words just to see the width of the textblock.
Plus some more random words just to see the width of the textblock.



\begin{myquote}
  This is in a \verb!myquote! environment. Have a look at the font size
  compared with the normal font size.
\end{myquote}

Some random words just to see the width of the textblock.
Plus some more random words just to see the width of the textblock.


\end{document}
```

[image]

So, you can use the regular `quote` environment and each time specify how the text should look, or you can (re)define the `quote` environment along the lines of `myquote` to give a fixed text appearance. More esotericaly you could define a version of the `quote` environment that took a parameter specifying the look of the text.